# Python class method chaining

Tags: python, python-2.7, magic-methods

To avoid getting lost in architectural decisions, I'll ask this with an analogous example:

lets say I wanted a Python class pattern like this:

```
queue = TaskQueue(broker_conn)
queue.region("DFW").task(fn, "some arg")
```

The question here is how do I get a design a class such that certain methods can be "chained" in this fashion.

`task()` would require access to the `queue` class instance attributes and the operations of `task` depends on the output of `region()`.

I see SQLalchemy does this (see below) but am having difficulty digging through their code and isolating this pattern.

```
query = db.query(Task).filter(Task.objectid==10100)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

SQLAlchemy produces a clone on such calls, see [`Generative._generate()` method](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/3dc9f9b3db10254f688c6b25b58951a4b1d4a41b/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/base.py#L158) which simply returns a clone of the current object.

On each generative method call (such as `.filter()`, `.orderby()`, etc.) a new clone is returned, with a specific aspect altered (such as the query tree expanded, etc.).

SQLAlchemy uses a [`@_generative` decorator](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/3dc9f9b3db10254f688c6b25b58951a4b1d4a41b/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/base.py#L39) to mark methods that must operate and return a clone here, swapping out `self` for the produced clone.

Using this pattern in your own code is quite simple:

```
from functools import wraps

class GenerativeBase(object):
    def _generate(self):
        s = self.__class__.__new__(self.__class__)
        s.__dict__ = self.__dict__.copy()
        return s

def _generative(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def decorator(self, *args, **kw):
        new_self = self._generate()
        func(new_self, *args, **kw)
        return new_self
    return decorator


class TaskQueue(GenerativeBase):
    @_generative
    def region(self, reg_id):
        self.reg_id = reg_id

    @_generative
    def task(self, callable, *args, **kw):
        self.tasks.append((callable, args, kw))
```

Each call to `.region()` or `.task()` will now produce a clone, which the decorated method updates by altering the state. The clone is then returned, leaving the original instance object unchanged.

Comment: Actually I think the solution is what I'm looking for, but having difficulty implementing it: http://pastebin.com/HpsgK0T5 - I been trying to debug it, but have been unsuccessful, 'TaskQueue' object is not callable

Comment: @NFicano: you changed the signature of the decorator; you replaced `self` with `fn`.

Comment: @NFicano: I see now that I did make a typo in my answer; corrected `fn(...)` to `func(...)`.

Comment: AH no I didn't see your edit, I knew fn wasn't right, but couldn't figure out what it was suppose to refer to, thanks again!

Comment: @MartijnPieters s = `self.__class__.__new__(self.__class__)` what does this line mean? does `self.__class__` refer to the child or base class? and what does `self.__new__` mean?

Comment: @HalcyonAbrahamRamirez: see [`object.__new__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__); `instance.__class__` is the class that produced the instance. It produces a *new* instance of the same class, whatever 'the same class' means for the current instance.

Comment: so `instance.__class__` basically refers to the name of the class where `instance.__class__` is called? so in your `class TaskQueue`  since you decorated `region` and `.__class__` is called in the `@_generative` decorator   so `.__class__` is  `TaskQueue`? which is the name of the class

Comment: @HalcyonAbrahamRamirez: no, it is the actual class object. The same object that `type(instance)` returns.

Comment: @MartijnPieters  I tested .__class__ in IDLE and it refers to the class name? for example lets say `class Num` has a class attribute called `digit` and is = 5 so that's `digit = 5` I tried `print(a.__class__.page)` outputs `5` so it is "basically" calling the class name. like how you would call a class attribute?

Comment: @HalcyonAbrahamRamirez: this is going way beyond what comments are usable for. Can you please use chat for this? There is a [Python chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) for example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84828/discussion-between-halcyon-abraham-ramirez-and-martijn-pieters).

Answer (score 6):

Just return the current object from `region` method, like this

```
def region(self, my_string):
    ...
    ...
    return self
```

Since `region` returns the current object which has the `task` function, the chaining is possible now.

**Note:**

As @chepner [mentioned in the comments section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21785689/python-class-method-chaining/21785714?noredirect=1#comment32961170_21785714), make sure that `region` makes changes to the object `self`.

Comment: Also, `region` needs to modify `self` in some way, since presumably `queue.region("DFW").task(fn, "some arg")` should be different from `queue.task(fn, "some arg")`. Or, `region()` should return not `self`, but some other `TaskQueue` object (or, whatever object has a `task` method).

Comment: You'll need to return a *clone* here; one that is a copy of `self` but with the changes applied.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Why so? Could you please explain?

Comment: @thefourtheye: That's what SQLAlchemy does: return you a new instance object that then allows further filtering. The original query object is not affected.

Comment: @thefourtheye how exactly do we modify self?