# Return self in class method - is this good approach?

Tags: python, class, oop, self

I have a class like below

```
class TestClass(object):

    def __init__(self, data):
            self.data = data

    def method_a(self, data):
            self.data += data/2
            return self

    def method_b(self, data):
            self.data += data
            return self

    def method_c(self, data):
            self.data -= data
            return self
```

Every method returns self. I wrote it that way to be albe to call few metohds in a chain, ie. `object.method_a(10).method_b(12).method_c(11)`. I was told that `return self` in method doesn't return current object, but creates new one. Is it really how it works? Is it good practice to use `return self` in python methods?

Comment: `return self` does **not** create a new object, you were told wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it really how it works?

No, it won't create a new object, it will return the same instance. You can check it by using `is` keyword, which checks if two objects are the same:

```
t = TestClass(3)
c = t.method_a(4)

print t is c
>>> True
```

> Is it good practice to use return self in python methods?

Yes, it's often used to allow chaining.

Answer (score 3):

`return self` does **not** create a new object, you were told wrong.

If you want to build an API that supports chaining, returning `self` is a fine practice. You may *want* to build a new object instead for a chaining API, but that's not a requirement either.

See [Python class method chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21785689/python-class-method-chaining/21785906#21785906) for how the SQLAlchemy library handles chaining with new instances per change. Creating a new object when mutating objects in a chain allows you to re-use partial transformations as a starting point for several new objects with different chained transformations applied.

Answer (score 3):

Returning self does not create a new object.

I'm sure some people will tell you that method chaining is bad.  I don't agree that it is necessarily bad.  Writing an API that is designed for method chaining is a choice, and if you decide to do it you need to make sure everything works as people expect.  But if you decide to do it, then returning `self` is often the right thing to do.  (Sometimes, you may want to return a newly-created object instead.  It depends whether you want the chained methods to cumulatively modify the original object or not.)